# Should unclear questions with accepted (or plausible) answers be marked for closing?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

When a question is unclear or missing key elements that might lead to an answer — such as versions, logs, and whatnot — it should be flagged for closure. To the best of my knowledge this is for two reasons:

1. People may misinterpret the question and offer an answer or comment that addresses an unrelated issue, introducing confusion for people who may have a similar question in the future
2. A closed question that an OP really wants answered will *hopefully* result in a better-written edit that can lead to a reopening and proper solution to the problem

Examples of recent opaque questions:

- I cant seem to find drives like E or D, in ubuntu, every folder or file get saved in the desktop itself. Please help — [Source](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361404/1222991)
- I want to restrict a user to run a command only two times in Ubuntu … — [Source](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361327/1222991)
- Is there a way or program to create a key combination to enter a special character? […] Actually I just want to press alt + 61 and it returns an "=" and so with several codes, I don't need all the ascii but I do need several. — [Source](https://askubuntu.com/q/1360875/1222991)

For some of these, it may be possible to guess at what the objective is. However, if a question is as clear as mud and has an accepted or positively-voted answer, should it still be marked for closure?

Comment: I would say it depends, by generally yes. Besides, closing requires 5 different people to vote on it. If none were able to salvage the post, then it would probably be worth closing it. For example, the second question you linked has been salvaged, and it's much clearer. Although it may be an XY problem, it is clear what the OP is trying to achieve.